# How to place labels on top of the pie chart in python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a pie chart and place a label on top of the pie but not sure how to.
can some one please teach me how to place label on the pie?

Below is example of data.

```
Group    percent
[0,10]      0
[10,20]     3 
[20,30]    16
[30,40]    11 
[40,50]    23 
[50,60]    5
[60,70]    27
```

This is the desired format of pie chart I want.
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
data = df['percent']

labels = ['0~10%', '10~20%', '20~30%', '30~40%', '40~50%', '50~60%','60~70%']
colors = ['#fad9c1','#03396c', '#3b5998', '#63ace5', '#adcbe3','#e3f0ff']


def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(round(pct/100.*np.sum(allvals)))
    return "{:.1f}%\n{:d} hr\n".format(pct, absolute)

wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(data, colors=colors, autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, data),textprops=dict(color="black"))    
 
plt.setp(autotexts, size=8, weight="bold")

plt.show()
```

Comment: There is documentation for what you are asking here https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but I responded by changing the label I got from autotexts to the label I wanted to add.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
data = df['percent']

labels = ['0~10%', '10~20%', '20~30%', '30~40%', '40~50%', '50~60%','60~70%']
colors = ['#fad9c1','#03396c', '#3b5998', '#63ace5', '#adcbe3','#e3f0ff']

def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(round(pct/100.*np.sum(allvals)))
    return "{:.1f}%\n{:d} hr\n".format(pct, absolute)

wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(data, colors=colors, autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, data), textprops=dict(color="black"))    

for i in range(len(labels)):
    tmp = autotexts[i].get_text()
    new_label = labels[i]+'\n'+tmp.split('\n')[1]+'\n'
    autotexts[i].set_text(new_label)
    
plt.setp(autotexts, size=12, weight="bold")

plt.show()
```

[image]